# Getting started with angular assistance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to output Hello World, but all I get is {{"Hello World"}}. This is my first attempt of an angular app. Can anyone tell me what's missing in my code? I imported angular.min.js, I declared the app in app.js and attached it to html tag, but still I can't output hello world. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="bodyController">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Specs and Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Videos</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 " ></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 " >
          {{"Hello World"}}     
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-2 " ></div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller("BodyController", function(){
        this.foods = fruits;
        });


     var fruits = [
    { name: 'Apples', calories: 65, totalFat: '0g', Saturated Fat: '0g' Cholestrol 0mg, sodium: '1mg', totalCarbs: '17g', dietaryFiber: '3g', Sugar: '13g', Protein: '0g', vitaminA: '1%', vitaminC: 10%, Calcium: 1%, Iron: 1%},
    { name: 'Oranges', price: 5.95 },
    { name: 'Pineapple', price: 3.95 }
  ];
})();
```

Comment: One thing you might want to keep in mind in learning angular right now is that angular 2 is currently in beta with a full version to be released in an unknown amount of time but soon. So just be ready for changes. Also back to your code you put your jquery and bootstrap scripts at the bottom of the page but your custom and angular at the top of the page but that's likely to break things since angular inherits from jquery normally you want to load all scripts at the bottom of the page and in the order that they are needed so in your case probably jquery bootstrap angular then custom

Answer (score 0):

you have some syntax error in your app.controllers name (bodyController is difeerent to ) and in you fruit list. you need to be more carefull whit the syntax

whit this some changes you can see your hello world

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller("bodyController", function(){
        this.foods = fruits;
        });
    var fruits = [
        { name: 'Apples', calories: 65, totalFat: '0g', Saturated_Fat: '0g', Cholestrol: '0mg', 
          sodium: '1mg', totalCarbs: '17g', dietaryFiber: '3g', Sugar: '13g', 
          Protein: '0g', vitaminA: '1%', vitaminC: '10%', Calcium: '1%', Iron: '1%'
        },
        { name: 'Oranges', price: 5.95 },
        { name: 'Pineapple', price: 3.95 }
    ];
    })();
```